# MinGW terminal is missing functionality

Tags: terminal, mingw-w64

I've installed MinGW-builds and the 64-bit version of MinGW.

When I try to run the Run Terminal program from the install, I get the following output:

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-builds\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev4>echo off
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>
```

I cannot execute make and other commands that come with the installation, so it seems like I've somehow reverted to the basic Windows cmd terminal.

How can I identify why MinGW terminal is missing functionality?

I have previously installed MinGW using the package manager, as well as MSYS. I've removed them as best I can, and used CCleaner to clean up references to them.

I checked my PATH but I cannot see obvious issues:

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-builds\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev4\mingw64\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Users\James\Desktop\bpmndev\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;
C:\Windows\System32;
C:\Go\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install MSYS again. It works with MinGW-w64 (actually it should work with any MinGW version). Just open the MSYS terminal, configure with options like "--build=x86_64-w64-mingw32" and make.